# GAP: Rubik's Cube Group - Thistlethwaite's algorithm

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, gap, rubiks-cube

In GAP let $G_0$ be the Rubik's Cube Group defined by the six moves

```
U := (1,3,8,6)(2,5,7,4)(9,33,25,17)(10,34,26,18)(11,35,27,19);
L := (9,11,16,14)(10,13,15,12)(1,17,41,40)(4,20,44,37)(6,22,46,35);
F := (17,19,24,22)(18,21,23,20)(6,25,43,16)(7,28,42,13)(8,30,41,11);
R := (25,27,32,30)(26,29,31,28)(3,38,43,19)(5,36,45,21)(8,33,48,24);
B := (33,35,40,38)(34,37,39,36)(3,9,46,32)(2,12,47,29)(1,14,48,27);
D := (41,43,48,46)(42,45,47,44)(14,22,30,38)(15,23,31,39)(16,24,32,40);
G0 := Group([U, L, F, R, B, D]);
```

Then define the subgroups, see *[Thistlethwaite's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_solutions_for_Rubik%27s_Cube)*

```
G1 := Subgroup(G0, [L,   R,   F,   B,   U^2, D^2]); 
G2 := Subgroup(G0, [L,   R,   F^2, B^2, U^2, D^2]);
G3 := Subgroup(G0, [L^2, R^2, F^2, B^2, U^2, D^2]);
```

I try to define quotient groups with GAP, but unfortunately I get the following error:

```
FactorGroup(G2, G3);
Error, <N> must be a normal subgroup of <G> at /proc/cygdrive/C/gap-4.11.0/lib/grp.gi:2569 called from
<function "FactorGroup">( <arguments> )
 called from read-eval loop at *stdin*:13
you can 'quit;' to quit to outer loop, or
you can 'return;' to continue
```

I do not understand this error since

```
IsNormal(G3, G2);
true
```

tells me that $G_3$ is indeed normal in $G_2$. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: that's not what IsNormal means - it returns true if G3 is *contained in the normalizer of* G2.

Comment: It might be useful to note here that the general convention in GAP for arguments of a function is that the larger objects come before the smaller one. So the paremeters are always in the order supergroup, subgroup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thistlethwaite's algorithm uses coset spaces, not factor groups. The groups aren't normal. The function is `IsNormal(G, H)`, i.e. the bigger group goes first, but you're plugging in the smaller group first. As [GroupProps notes](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/GAP:IsNormal), "Note that if the order of the group and the subgroup are interchanged, GAP will not detect an error and will return true, because any subgroup of a group normalizes the whole group."